# What's the difference between hacks and messy/bad code

Tags: security

When is code a hack?

People seem to define a hack as ugly coding to solve a problem but how is that different from writing messy code.

Also is the only difference between a problem coded badly and a problem hacked the mindset of the programmer?

When I say hack I mean in the programming/development sense not the illegal sense.

Comment: Well, according to the media, a hack is a security breach...

Comment: I'd suggest its the mind set of the observer but I'm not looking to start a debate about Objective Truth. I guess you are suggesting that a Hack is resilient and efficient code that is hard to read. I guess that is what comments are for.

Comment: @delnan: Then that definition MUST be wrong... media never gets it right ;-)

Comment: To me, a hack is something that is not obvious. But this question is *really* subjective, as nobody can properly define such a vague term.

Comment: A hack isn't necessarily "ugly coding", at least not in the sense that it's messy or bad. I'd say it's more like a workaround that the programmer doesn't feel is the most elegant possible solution, but is either the only thing they can do given the circumstances or the only thing they could come up with at the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hack is a section of code you write to overcome a technology deficiency such as your programming language, communications protocol, hardware, or some other programmer's bug.  You usually tag your code as a hack to let other people know you could have done it the "right" way if you just didn't have this limitation.

That being said, it is often misused and simply refers to a section of code where the programmer was too lazy to do it the "right" way, or where the code seems to work for what they designed, but they are aren't sure of the unintended consequences. For example: one may "hack" code if it was poorly designed and they don't understand what the change is going to really do to the entire system.  That isn't really a hack, it is just a lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

A hack is an ugly solution which may be implemented in well documented, perfectly formatted code with exquisitely named variables and all that. As they say, you can put lipstick on a pig, but it's still a pig.

On the other hand, you can also have a messy, hard to read implementation of a beautiful algorithm. Poorly chosen names, bad formatting, and poor documentation make code harder to understand, but the underlying idea may still be sound. This sort of thing isn't lipstick on a pig, it's a diamond in the rough.

Answer (score 0):

A hack implies that the programmer is using a system in a way it was not designed for. For a hack to take place, the system must have a clear way it was designed. This design is then violated by the hack.

Ugly coding usually implies there is no clear design to hack. A hack is no longer a hack if it is just as ugly as the surrounding code.

Normally hacks are quick and dirty solutions which the programmer intents to rectify some day. Ugly programming has a way of never getting fixed.